# Using predict() on statsmodels.formula data with different column names using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statsmodels

I've got some regressions results from running `statsmodels.formula.api.ols`. Here's a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

example_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3))
example_df.columns = ["a", "b", "c"]
fit = smf.ols('a ~ b', example_df).fit()
```

I'd like to apply the model to column `c`, but a naive attempt to do so doesn't work:

```
fit.predict(example_df["c"])
```

Here's the exception I get:

```
PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'b' is not defined
    a ~ b
        ^
```

I can do something gross and create a new, temporary `DataFrame` in which I rename the column of interest:

```
example_df2 = pd.DataFrame(example_df["c"])
example_df2.columns = ["b"]
fit.predict(example_df2)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? (short of switching to `statsmodels.api` instead of `statsmodels.formula.api`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
>>> fit.predict({"b": example_df["c"]})
array([ 0.84770672, -0.35968269,  1.19592387, -0.77487812, -0.98805215,
        0.90584753, -0.15258093,  1.53721494, -0.26973941,  1.23996892])
```

or create a numpy array for the prediction, although that is much more complicated if there are categorical explanatory variables:

```
>>> fit.predict(sm.add_constant(example_df["c"].values), transform=False)
array([ 0.84770672, -0.35968269,  1.19592387, -0.77487812, -0.98805215,
        0.90584753, -0.15258093,  1.53721494, -0.26973941,  1.23996892])
```

Comment: Did you find this in the documentation somewhere? [My attempt](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.predict.html) didn't turn anything up.

Comment: I might have seen it in one of the notebook examples. However, patsy is handling the formula information and construction of the design matrix, and in most or in all cases the data can be specified as pandas dataframe or any other dictionary like data structure. This will not be explicitly documented for each method or model.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your `fit` definition with this line:

```
fit = smf.ols('example_df.a ~ example_df.b', example_df).fit()
```

It should work.

```
fit.predict(example_df["c"])

array([-0.52664491, -0.53174346, -0.52172484, -0.52819856, -0.5253607 ,
       -0.52391618, -0.52800043, -0.53350634, -0.52362988, -0.52520823])
```

Comment: Or fit = smf.ols("example_df['a'] ~ example_df['b']", example_df).fit() if you prefer the other style of column reference.

Comment: I'm not getting the correct results with this, with the version of patsy and pandas that I have installed. Check with `example_df["c"] * fit.params[1] + fit.params[0]`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. `fit.predict` seems to be ignoring the argument. I get the same output if I use `fit.predict(None)`.